# Keep First Non-Zero Element, Set All Others to 0

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have a 2-d NumPy array that looks like this:

```
array([[0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0. , 0.3, 0. ]])
```

I'd like to modify it so that each row consists of all 0's, except for the first non-zero entry.  If it's all 0s to start with, we don't change anything.

I could do this:

```
example = np.array([[0,0, 0.2, 0.2], [0.3, 0, 0.3, 0]])
my_copy = np.zeros_like(example)
for i, row in enumerate(example):
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        if elem > 0:
            my_copy[i, j] = elem
            break
```

But that's ugly and not vectorized.  Any suggestions for how to vectorize this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a wanted result example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
e =np.zeros(example.shape)
rows = np.arange(example.shape[0])
cols =  np.argmax(example != 0, 1)
e[rows, cols] = example[rows, cols]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a vectorised solution. The trick is to calculate your first non-zero entries via `bool` conversion and `argmax`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.2],
              [0.3, 0. , 0.3, 0. ],
              [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])

res = np.zeros(A.shape)
idx =  np.arange(res.shape[0])
args = A.astype(bool).argmax(1)
res[idx, args] = A[idx, args]

print(res)

array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0.2,  0. ],
       [ 0.3,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
x = np.array([[0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.2],
          [0.3, 0. , 0.3, 0. ],
          [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Using **`logical_and`** with **`np.eye`**:

```
m = (x!=0).argmax(1)
x[~np.logical_and(x, np.eye(x.shape[1])[m])] = 0
```

Output:

```
array([[0. , 0. , 0.2, 0. ],
       [0.3, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Using this method will be slightly slower than the other two suggested.

Comment: Can you update yours so that it dynamically calculates rows, I don't want to mess up the answer :P  I think it would just be `np.arange(len(example))`

Comment: Updated, very fast.

Comment: Its faster with `idx = np.arange(res.shape[0])` for the first approach.

Comment: @Divakar yea the first and 3rd approaches are pretty much identical, but `range` is hella slow.  Are you planning on putting us all to shame with an answer? :)